# Фильтрация полей формы с автокомплитом

Tags: angular, rxjs

Форма содержит поля с автокомплитом. При выборе элемента, он должен пропадать из выпадающего списка и добавляться обратно при удалении chips. Как можно отрефакторить `listeningControls()`, чтобы избавиться от повторяющегося кода? Есть мысль valueChanges навесить на `parentFormGroup` и в пайпе отфильтровать контролы, с которыми не ведется взаимодействие. Но нет понимая как эти контролы различать

переработан [пример из документации Angular Material](https://stackblitz.com/angular/peqmdeaqyyx?file=app%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.ts)

```js
export class ChipsAutocompleteExample {
  visible = true;
  selectable = true;
  removable = true;

  fruitCtrl = new FormControl();
  filteredFruits: Observable < string[] > ;
  fruits: string[] = ['Lemon'];
  allFruits: string[] = ['Apple', 'Lemon', 'Lime', 'Orange', 'Strawberry'];

  cityCtrl = new FormControl();
  filteredCityList: Observable < string[] > ;
  allCity: string[] = ['LA', 'Chicago', 'London', 'Milan'];
  cityList: string[] = ['Chicago'];

  @Input() parentFormGroup: FormGroup;

  @ViewChild('fruitInput', {
    static: false
  }) fruitInput: ElementRef < HTMLInputElement > ;
  @ViewChild('cityInput', {
    static: false
  }) cityInput: ElementRef < HTMLInputElement > ;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createControlForAutocomplete();
    this.listeningControls();
  }

  listeningControls(): void {
    this.filteredFruits = this.parentFormGroup.get('fruit').pipe(
      startWith(null),
      map((fruit: string | null) => fruit ? this._filter(fruit, 'fruit') : this.allFruits.slice()),
      map(fruits => fruits.filter(fruit => !this.fruits.includes(fruit))),
    );

    this.filteredCityList = this.cityCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(null),
      map((city: string | null) => city ? this._filter(city, 'city') : this.allCity.slice()),
      map(cityList => cityList.filter(city => !this.cityList.includes(city))),
    );
  }
  createControlForAutocomplete(): void {
    this.fruitCtrl = this.fb.control('');
    this.cityCtrl = this.fb.control('');
  }

  remove(value: string, ctrlName: string): void {
    const control = this.parentFormGroup.get(ctrlName);
    const index = control.value.indexOf(value);

    if (index > -1) {
      const temp = [...control.value];
      temp.splice(index, 1);
      control.setValue([...temp]);
    }
  }

  selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent, ctrlName: 'fruit' | 'city'): void {
    const control = this.parentFormGroup.get(ctrlName);
    const temp = [...control.value, event.option.value];
    control.setValue(temp);
    (this[ctrlName + 'Input'] as ElementRef < HTMLInputElement > ).nativeElement.value = '';
  }
}

private _filter(value: string, ctrlName: 'fruit' | 'city'): string[] {
  const currentControl = this[ctrlName];
  const selectedItems = this.parentFormGroup.get(ctrlName).value;

  if (!value) {
    return currentControl.slice();
  }

  currentControl.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().includes(value));

  return currentControl.filter(item => {
    return item !== value && !selectedItems.includes(item);
  });

}
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipFruitList aria-label="Fruit selection">
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(fruit)">
      {{fruit}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input placeholder="New fruit..." #fruitInput [formControl]="fruitCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [matChipInputFor]="chipFruitList">
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event, 'fruit')">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
      {{fruit}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipCityList aria-label="City selection">
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let city of cityList" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(city)">
      {{city}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input placeholder="New city..." #cityInput [formControl]="cityCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="autoCity" [matChipInputFor]="chipCityList">
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-autocomplete #autoCity="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event, 'city')">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let city of filteredCityList | async" [value]="city">
      {{fruit}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё верно, фильтровать нужно в конструкторе. Нужно добавить еще один `map`:

```
constructor() {
  this.filteredFruits = this.fruitCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(null),
      map((fruit: string | null) => fruit ? this._filter(fruit) : this.allFruits.slice()),
      map(fruits => fruits.filter(fruit => !this.fruits.includes(fruit))),
    );
}
```

Ну и дальше в шаблоне

```html
<mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
  {{fruit}}
</mat-option>
```

Comment: а как, чтобы он добавлялся обратно при вызове метода `remove()`?

Comment: он добавится автоматически, так как `this.fruits` перестане сожержать удалённый элемент

Comment: хм. Ваш код скопировала в пример, выдается ошибка `Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]'.`

Comment: это какая-то дурацкая ошибка stackblitz.

Comment: можно сделать так: `map(fruits => fruits.filter(fruit => this.fruits.indexOf(fruit) === -1))`, будет то же самое

Comment: сорри, поправил последний каммент. Так будет работать.

Comment: @sneas +1. Добавь пожалуйста в свой ответ пример использования в шаблоне, что-то типа `*ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits$ | async" ` :) Чтоб так сказать отпали любые вопросы в роде "а как это юзать?" :D

Comment: @overthesanity 

Comment: @elie_ если ответ решает твою проблему, то пометь его галочкой :)